# Bingo card multidimensional array giving undefined offset on last column

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a 6x6 bingo card which is generated with random numbers between 10 and 70. The 7th row and 7th column are used to count the drawn numbers that are on the card. When a row or column reaches 6, there is bingo.

The eventual result I get is right, but in the proces of getting there a few things are going wrong.

In my function generateCard I create the rows and columns of numbers for the card. I think the problem lies in this function.

```
function generateCard()
{

$card = array();

    for ($row = 1; $row < 8; ++$row)
    {

        $card[$row] = array();

        $deck = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

        for ($kolom = 1; $kolom < 8; ++$kolom) {

            $index = mt_rand(0,count($deck) - 1);
            $number = $deck[$index];
            $card[$row][] = $row . $number;
            unset($deck[$index]);
            $deck = array_values($deck);

        }
        //Test
        printCard($card);

        // 7th column
        $card[$row][7] = 0;
    }
    //Test
    printCard($card);

    // 7th row
    for ($kolom = 1; $kolom < 7; ++$kolom){
        $card[7][$kolom] = 0;
    }

//Test
printCard($card);
return $card;
}
```

I've put in a few printCard functions to test the outcome.

The first test above the creation of the 7th column gives me a ton of undefined offset 7 notices. I figured this happens because the column does not exist, but when I try to create this earlier, I still get the notices.

The second test above the 7th row shows that the 7th row (which should be 0) gets filled with numbers. This gets overwritten after with 0 values. I figured I could fix this by putting $row < 7 and $kolom < 7, but when I do this the card won't get printed right at all.

I'm wondering why i'm getting all these undefined offset notices about the last column (even when I create it earlier) and why I can't use $row < 7 and $column < 7 in both the for loops of generate card to avoid filling up the last row  and column (7x7) with values. These should be 0 before the bingo game starts.

Do you have any suggestions?

I think i'm overlooking a few things here..
I will put the complete code here:

```
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

function generateCard()
{

$card = array();

for ($row = 1; $row < 8; ++$row)
{

    $card[$row] = array();

    $deck = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

    for ($kolom = 1; $kolom < 8; ++$kolom) {

        $index = mt_rand(0,count($deck) - 1);
        $number = $deck[$index];
        $card[$row][] = $row . $number;
        unset($deck[$index]);
        $deck = array_values($deck);

    }
    //Test
    printCard($card);

    // 7th column
    $card[$row][7] = 0;
}
//Test
printCard($card);

// 7th row
for ($kolom = 1; $kolom < 7; ++$kolom){
    $card[7][$kolom] = 0;
}

//Test
printCard($card);
return $card;
}


function printCard($card){ ?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <?php for($rij = 1; $rij < 8; $rij++) { ?>
        <tr> 
            <?php for ($kolom = 1; $kolom < 8; $kolom++) { ?>
                <td<?php if (($card[$rij][7] == 6) || ($card[7][$kolom] == 6)) {  echo ' style="background-color:green"'; } ?>><?php echo $card[$rij][$kolom]; ?></td> 
            <?php } 
            } ?>
        </tr>
</table>
<?php }

$card = generateCard();

$getrokkenGetallen = array();

$deck = range(10,69);

$bingo = false;

while (!$bingo){

$index = mt_rand(0,count($deck) - 1);

$number = $deck[$index];


if(!in_array($number, $getrokkenGetallen)){

    unset($deck[$index]);

    $deck = array_values($deck);

    $getrokkenGetallen[] = $number;

    for ($row = 1; $row < 7; $row++) {
        for ($kolom = 1; $kolom < 7; $kolom++) {           
            if ($card[$row][$kolom] == $number) {

                $card[$row][7] += 1;
                $card[7][$kolom] += 1;

                if(($card[$row][7] == 6) || ($card[7][$kolom] == 6)){
                        $bingo = true;
                }
                break; 
            }  
        }
    }
}
}

echo '<h2>Bingokaart waarop BINGO is gevallen</h2>';

printCard($card);

echo '<p><strong>Getrokken getallen:</strong><br>';
foreach($getrokkenGetallen as $value)
{
    echo $value . ' ';
}
echo '</p>';


echo '<p><strong>Aantal getallen dat is getrokken:</strong> ';
echo count($getrokkenGetallen);
echo '</p>';
```

Example of the output:

[image: Output of current code]

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason your bingo cards rows always contain numbers in successive powers of ten, rather than just a set of random numbers? I realise it won't make much difference to the distribution of the numbers, it's just am aesthetic thing.

Comment: Yes, each row contains it's own range of numbers starting at 10-19, 20-29, et cetera. It's part of the result that I need, but it also keeps it nice and organised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where your error comes from, and I'm not a regular PHP user, but if i change the `generateCard` function to this:

```
function generateCard(){

  $card = array();

  for ($row = 1; $row < 8; ++$row){

    $card[$row] = array();
    $deck = range($row*10, $row*10+9);
    shuffle($deck);
    for($col = 1; $col < 8; ++$col){
      if($row == 7 OR $col == 7){
        $card[$row][$col] = 0;
      }else{
        $card[$row][$col] = $deck[$col];
      }
    }
  }

  //Test
  printCard($card);
  return $card;
}
```

It all works as expected. It's a little simpler than the route you were going i think.